# Pandas_datareader error. No module named 'distutils'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am using python 3.12 on Pycharm and I have been trying to use the pandas_datareader module. After doing "pip install pandas_datareader" in the Command Prompt, I went to the documentation to look at where to begin. After trying what they said to do, I got an error saying "No module named 'distutils'"

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

pdr.get_data_fred('AAPL')
```

That is the code I used

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install setuptools` (or pipenv)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an earlier version of python.
distutils was deprecated in python 3.10, and removed in python 3.12.
https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#distutils